# call python module functions from command line

Tags: python, function, module, distutils, setup.py

I would like to know if there is a way to call module functions from the command line. My problem is that I have a file package called find_mutations. This requires that the input files are sorted in a specific way, so i made a function to do so. I would like the user to be able to have the option to run the code normally:

```
$ python -m find_mutations -h
```

or run the specific sort_files function:

```
$ python -m find_mutations.sort_files -h
```

Is something like this possible? If so, does the sort_files function need to be in its own strip? Do I need to add something to my `__init__.py` script? The package install properly and runs fine, I would just like to add this.

Comment: Would you accept something like `$ python -m find_mutations sort_files`? See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: as long as it is a convenient way to run `find_mutations` and `sort_files` after the package has been installed, both of which use different inputs for argparse

Comment: Installed how? As scripts by `setup.py`? Sub commands can handle different arguments, but some rearrangement might be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add flags to run the function. The following example is not a good way to work with command arguments, but demonstrates the idea.

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if '-s' in sys.argv:
        sort_files()
```

Add a flag to run the specific function, in this case `-s` to sort the files.